# MiniCssExtractPlugin is not creating css file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm implementing server side rendering with React/Node and CSS Modules are no longer working.

I've brought in mini-css-extract-plugin to extract the CSS from the JS and the plugin is not creating a css file in the public folder (or anywhere).

/package.json

```
{
  ....
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "server": "babel-node ./src/server/index.js",
    "client": "webpack --watch --progress",
    "start": "yarn server & yarn client"
  },
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/node": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-css-modules-transform": "^1.6.2",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.6.0",
    "react-frontload": "^1.0.7",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  }
}
```

/webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/client/index.js',
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'build.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  resolve: {extensions: ['.js', '.css']},
  watch: false,
  plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin({filename: 'styles.css'})],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        sideEffects: true,
        use: [{loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader}, 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          cacheDirectory: true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

/.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        ["css-modules-transform", {
          "generateScopedName": "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
        }]
    ]
}
```

I expect to see the following file be created /public/styles.css and right now no file is being created in that folder or anywhere else. Thanks for your help!

Comment: how did you solve it?

Comment: I don't think `mini-css-extract-plugin` works with `target: 'node'`

Answer (score 1):

Check my below config

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        }),
   ],
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            minimize: true,
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Please let me know if you still have problem

Comment: I tried it, didn't work for me, no css file was created in the build folder, any other advice?

Comment: Did you include css file in your js ?